# ListView set Column datatemplate(celltemplateselector) depending on the data from another column

Tags: xaml, listview, datatemplateselector

I have a ListView as you can see in the code below:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="75" x:Name="_lstvSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding Search.SearchExpressions}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Field name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Fields, 
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Field, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Field.UserFriendlyFieldName"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Operator">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Field.Operators}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Operator, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Operator"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                            <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector>
                                <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.Alpha>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.Alpha>
                                <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.Numeric>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <igEditors:XamNumericEditor Value="{Binding Value}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.Numeric>
                                <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.CheckBox>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.CheckBox>
                                <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.DateTime>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor Value="{Binding Value}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.DateTime>
                                <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.DropDownItem>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.DropDownItem>
                                <vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.Generic>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector.Generic>
                            </vm:FieldValueTemplateSelector>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="AND/OR">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ConditionLinks, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding BooleanOperator, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Remove">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Remove" IsEnabled="{Binding IsValid}" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

My problem is that I wan't the CellTemplate form the **Value** column to be changed depending on the the selection from the first column **Field Name** but how do I trigger this.

When the filed is chosen I have a property in my model cald FieldDatatype from which I determine the type of the filed chosen in the first column. As you can see in the **Value** column I have set an CellTemplateSelector(FieldValueTemplateSelector) but this set's only once the datatemplate and doesn't refresh when I select other field from the first column.

Comment: I have a similar problem as well